# is it possible to have fetchmail trigger a script when it finds an unread email

Tags: linux, shell, cron

I have a GMail account that is set to only receive an email with a certain subject.
I need some linux commands to trigger when it finds unread versions of this email.
The commands are just application calls so I could record my desktop while it runs.

```
xrandr --size 1360x768
timeout 2h recordmydesktop
xrandr --size 1366x768
```

I already created a filter on gmail for the email itself, but now I have no idea what to do next. I was told to set up fetchmail that would fetch unread emails in the folder I set-up.(and mark the newly fetched email as read on gmail so it wouldn't read the same mail over and over). This is the script I got, but i'm not sure if ths script does what I need it to.

```
poll imap.gmail.com protocol IMAP 
   user "l**********@gmail.com"
   password '*****'
   folder 'Pic*******'
   fetchmail -c
   keep
   ssl
```

Next is that I was told to set up a procmail script to trigger my linux commands whenever fetchmail says that it found an unread version of the email. but I'm not exactly sure how to do it. I also need to set up cronjob to have this script trigger every few minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requirement to run X commands somewhat complicates matters. Cron is not really suitable -- even if your computer is only turned on when you are logged in, the general X architecture is based on privilege separation -- commands running in your current X session have access to the GUI, others do not.

Running Fetchmail and Procmail from within your X session is kind of awkward as well, but if you have a dedicated email account for this task, I don't suppose you mind accidentally losing an email message occasionally.

Thus, instead of a Cron job, I would suggest a simple background script running from your `.xsession` or similar.

```
#!/bin/sh
while true; do
    fetchmail -N -d0 -f $HOME/.fetchmailrc -m "/usr/bin/procmail $HOME/.procmailrc"
    sleep 600
done
```

The Procmail recipe could look something like

```
:0
* ^Subject: whatever
| xrandr --size 1360x768 ;\
  timeout 2h recordmydesktop; \
  xrandr --size 1366x768
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I'm having trouble with fetch mail. I'm getting this error.
'5 messages (5 seen) for User@gmail.com at imap.gmail.com (folder).
fetchmail: mailbox selection failed
fetchmail: client/server synchronization error while fetching from User@gmail.com@imap.gmail.com
fetchmail: Query status=7 (ERROR)
'

Comment: Quick googling for this error message suggests a variety of reasons, but my guess would be that you forgot to disable the cron job. See http://askubuntu.com/a/194080/25077

Comment: I'll note that this builds on @John1024's answer.

Answer (score 1):

`fetchmail` is good at downloading messages.  `procmail` is good at filtering messages and executing arbitrary linux commands based on the mail received.

To set up `fetchmail` to run every 10 minutes as a cronjob and pass the mail it receives to `procmail`, run `crontab -e` and add the following line:

```
*/10 * * * *  /usr/bin/fetchmail -N -d0 -f $HOME/.fetchmailrc -m "/usr/bin/procmail $HOME/.procmailrc"
```

You will need to create a `~/.procmailrc` file to do the filtering and executing.

You have not said what commands you want to run.  As an example, just for the purpose of giving you ideas, the following stanza from a `~/.procmailrc` file selects messages from `somebody@example.com` with the subject heading `New File`.  The body of the message is then uudecoded and the output from the uudecoder is then untarred:

```
:0 w
* ^From:.*somebody@example.com
* ^Subject: New File
| uudecode -o /dev/stdout | tar -xzC /var/tmp/
```

Comment: The commands are just application calls so I could record something while it runs.

'xrandr --size 1360x768

firefox "https://picarto.tv/live/channel.php?watch=Mikeinel" &

timeout 5m recordmydesktop

xrandr --size 1366x768'

Comment: @LawrenceEsguerra I don't know what specifically you mean by the phrase "record something" but, in all likelihood, yes. The possibilities are endless.

Comment: Do you mind to help me make that /.procmailrc script? I'm looking into procmail, but most tuts I find don't make sense for my poor stupid head. Sorry for being a noob and thanks for the help.I edited the main question so the commands I want to trigger are written. Please and thank you.